# Why does my shape have a tiny horizontal line?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, vector, path, character-design

I need to remove the horizontal bar of an A char so it looks like a V upside down. What I did is: I opened Illustrator and typed the character A, then I clicked "create outlines". Then I joined bottom left anchor point of the horizontal bar with the top left one and did the same with the other side.

That removes the horizontal bar but it leaves a tiny horizontal line, I tried removing the path left but the line still remains.

[image: tiny horizontal line]

Here is the .ai file:  http://www.sendspace.com/file/d9je5o

How can I remove the horizontal bar from the A completely without getting that horizontal line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shape is unclosed. With the shape selected, open the **Pathfinder** panel and click the ***Unite*** button.

[image: Pathfinder Pane]